# why is my Capybara selector not finding the target?

Tags: capybara

I have a page with two forms. It's a nic setting form. I have given everything a css id just to make them easily selectable.

```
%form#mnic_form
  .datagrid
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th{:colspan => "2"} 
            = "(eth0 - Management) Port Settings (#{@a.get_management_nic["mac"]})"
      %tbody#managementnic
        %tr
          %td
            DHCP:
          %td
            %input#dhcpon1{:type => "radio", :name => "dhcp", :value => "true", :checked => @a.get_management_nic["dhcp"], :onclick => "dhcpHandler('management')"} Enabled
            %br
            %input#dhcpoff1{:type => "radio", :name => "dhcp", :value => "false", :checked => !@a.get_management_nic["dhcp"], :onclick => "dhcpHandler('management')"} Disabled
        %tr
          %td
            IP Address:
          %td
            %input#ip1{:type => "text", :name => "ip", :value => @a.get_management_nic["ip"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#ip1')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            Subnet Mask:
          %td
            %input#subnet1{:type => "text", :name => "subnet", :value => @a.get_management_nic["subnet"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#subnet1')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            Gateway:
          %td
            %input#gateway1{:type => "text", :name => "gateway", :value => @a.get_management_nic["gateway"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#gateway1')" }
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            DNS Servers:
          %td
            %input#dyndns1{:type => "checkbox", :name => "dynamicDNS", :value => "true", :checked => @a.get_management_nic["dynamicDNS"], :onclick => "dynamicDNSHandler('management')"}
            Automatically assign DNS from DHCP Server
        %tr
          %td
            DNS 1:
          %td
            %input#dns11{:type => "text", :name => "dns1", :value => @a.get_management_nic["dns1"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#dns11')" }
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            DNS 2:
          %td
            %input#dns21{:type => "text", :name => "dns2", :value => @a.get_management_nic["dns2"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#dns21')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
  %input#mnic_submit{:type => "button", :value => "Save", :onclick => "submitMNic()"}
%form#vnic_form
  .datagrid
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th{:colspan => "2"}
            = "(eth1 - Video) NIC Port Settings (#{@a.get_video_nic["mac"]})"
      %tbody#videonic
        %tr
          %td
            DHCP:
          %td
            %input#dhcpon2{:type => "radio", :name => "dhcp", :value => "true", :checked => @a.get_video_nic["dhcp"], :onclick => "dhcpHandler('video')"} Enabled
            %br
            %input#dhcpoff2{:type => "radio", :name => "dhcp", :value => "false", :checked => !@a.get_video_nic["dhcp"], :onclick => "dhcpHandler('video')"} Disabled
        %tr
          %td
            IP Address:
          %td
            %input#ip2{:type => "text", :name => "ip", :value => @a.get_video_nic["ip"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#ip2')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            Subnet Mask:
          %td
            %input#subnet2{:type => "text", :name => "subnet", :value => @a.get_video_nic["subnet"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#subnet2')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            Gateway:
          %td
            %input#gateway2{:type => "text", :name => "gateway", :value => @a.get_video_nic["gateway"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#gateway2')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            DNS Servers:
          %td
            %input#dyndns2{:type => "checkbox", :name => "dynamicDNS", :value => "true", :checked => @a.get_video_nic["dynamicDNS"], :onclick => "dynamicDNSHandler('video')"}
            Automatically assign DNS from DHCP Server
        %tr
          %td
            DNS 1:
          %td
            %input#dns12{:type => "text", :name => "dns1", :value => @a.get_video_nic["dns1"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#dns12')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
            DNS 2:
          %td
            %input#dns22{:type => "text", :name => "dns2", :value => @a.get_video_nic["dns2"], :onblur => "IPHandler('#dns22')"}
            %img.spinner{:src => '/img/busy_spinner.gif', :style => "display: none", :height => "15"}
        %tr
          %td
          %td
            %p All multicast routed on this interface

  %input#vnic_submit{:type => "button", :value => "Save", :onclick => "submitVNic()"}
```

Now when I go to test this using capybara, I try these two functions:

```
page.choose('dhcpoff1')
page.choose('dhcpoff2')
```

and the first one works perfectly, and the second one does nothing. This shouldn't be that difficult to figure out, but I'm completely stuck. Been staring at it for hours. I appreciate any insight you might have.

```
function dhcpHandler(m_or_v) {
    var tmp = (m_or_v === "management") ? tmp = $('#managementnic > tr > td > input') : tmp = $('#videonic > tr > td > input');
    if (tmp[0].checked) {
        tmp[2].disabled = true;
        tmp[3].disabled = true;
        tmp[4].disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        tmp[2].disabled = false;
        tmp[3].disabled = false;
        tmp[4].disabled = false;    
    }
}
```

---

More testing. There are controller methods above, so let me just say that the page starts with dhcpon2 selected, and ip2, gateway2, and subnet2 all disabled.

I'm trying to run `page.choose('dhcpoff2')` and get it to select dhcpoff2, and then trigger the dhcpHandler() to un-disable the 3 fields. a workaround that works is `page.execute_script("$('#dhcpoff2').click()")` but that's too unbearable. currently I have it failing in selenium (2.48.1, capybara 2.5.0), and working in poltergeist...??? so to be more specific, here's a test:

```
page.choose('dhcpoff2')
#page.execute_script("$('#dhcpoff2').click()")
assert !find('#ip2')["disabled"]
```

if we comment out line 2 (the ghetto work around) it passes with poltergeist as the driver, but not with selenium as the driver.

And finally, here's the driver setup I'm using, swapping which lines are commented to switch between poltergeist and selenium:

```
include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false, phantomjs: "C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/phantomjs.exe")
end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
#Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
#Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Comment: What driver are you using and what does dhcpHandler do?

Comment: I'm using :selenium, and :poltergeist (really poltergeist, but swapped to selenium so I could watch it go when things stopped making sense) both exhibit the weirdness of dhcpoff2 not working in the above case.
dhcphandler uses jquery to enable or disable the ip, gateway, and subnet fields based on which one's selected.

Comment: since it doesn't work in poltergeist or selenium post the dhcpHandler code

Comment: It's not the javascript that's not getting called, it's the choose function. The radio button that is given when you call $('#dhcpoff2') in the console does not get selected when you call page.choose('dhcpoff2') but the corresponding #dhcpoff1 does given the same pattern. However, no harm giving you the function. edited above.

Comment: The reason I asked about the dhcpHandler is because the way choose works is to click the radio button if it's not already checked, and if it is already checked it does nothing.  Therefore the onclick handler could have been interfering with something there.  That being said, I have tried to replicate the issue with the html and JS you have provided and it all appears to work fine for me with selenium-webdriver 2.48.1 and Capybara 2.5.0

Comment: I appreciate your looking into it. revisiting it now (after temporarily solving it with `page.execute_script("$('#dhcpoff2').click()")`) I've now got it running right with poltergeist, but failing with selenium? I edited above with details.

Comment: t's possible that your assert is running before the action from clicking #dhcpoff2 occurs - rather than the assert you have, you should use `assert_selector(:field, 'ip2', disabled: false)` or `assert page.has_field?('ip2', disabled: false)` (the first will give a better error message in case of failure) which will allow  Capybara to retry a few times waiting for the field to become enabled.

Comment: I figured out what was going on. this is going to be extremely unsatisfying. hold onto your shorts. the way selenium was coming up (the size and shape of the window) made the footer in the layout sit right over the disabled button I was trying to choose. if, when firefox came up, I manually scrolled down 1 click to put the radio button in full view, it worked. otherwise, it failed to select it. like the .choose method was simulating a click, and hitting the footer instead.